# How to compensate the energy of a spectrum after using a Tukey window

Tags: fft

I am trying to minimise the noise in a spectrum of a variable. I have divided the time history in equal parts, I have multiplied every part of the time history by a Tukey window, done a FFT of each one of this window. After this procedure I have an adequate signal, I have a question:
Should I compensate the energy lost with the Tukey window? and how?

Comment: Did you overlap the frames of windowed signal? See here: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/13436/choosing-the-right-overlap-for-a-window-function

Comment: @ZRHan Yes. I overlap

Comment: If your window and noverlap satisfy COLA, the synthesized signal doesn’t lose any energy due to windowing.

Comment: How is it possible? It is always a mean of FT made on a "weakened" (due to the Tukey window) signal.

Comment: But you have overlapped and added the frames.

Comment: I selected intervals of time history that overla, I did the fft of each one, and then the mean. what should I add?

Comment: Please see here: https://www.dsprelated.com/freebooks/sasp/Overlap_Add_OLA_STFT_Processing.html